# Hook does not toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have this hook that opens/closes some unique div's. I use `typescript`.

```
import { SetStateAction, useState } from "react";

export default function useOpened() {
  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState("closed");
  const open = (depName: SetStateAction<string>) =>
    setIsOpened(depName);
  return [isOpened, open];
}
```

This works and opens the div like so:

```
<button onClick={() => open(item.text)}>{item.text}</button>
{isOpened === item.text && (
<div>Text stuff</div>
)}
<button onClick={() => open(item.chapter)}>{item.chapter}</button>
{isOpened === item.chapter && (
<div>Chapter description</div>
)}
```

In my component, I get this problem: This expression is not callable. Not all constituents of type 'string | ((sectionName: SetStateAction) => void)' are callable. Type 'string' has no call signatures. --- How to fix?

Also I try to make the hook that it toggles between "open" and "close" the div's. I tried with `setState` but did not work. Also tried with `status` but that also did not work.

My code works but somehow when I want to open one div, then the other opened div closes. So always only one div is open always. Any other div I want to open, makes the previous one close automatically. Open/close a div should not affect any other div to open/close. Cannot figure out how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues with your code.

#### 1. Both buttons set the same state

The core issue is that those two buttons are in the same component, so they are setting the same state. If you want to two divs to open independently, you will either need to break those out into two separate components or have two separate calls to that hook.

Something like this should work: https://playcode.io/1730761

```
export function Component() {
  const [textOpened, openText] = useOpened();
  const [chapterOpened, openChapter] = useOpened();

  ...

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => openText(item.text)}>{item.text}</button>
        {textOpened === item.text && (
        <div>Text stuff</div>
      )}
      <button onClick={() => openChapter(item.chapter)}>{item.chapter}</button>
        {chapterOpened === item.chapter && (
        <div>Chapter description</div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

#### 2. Your hook returns an Array instead of an object

The example above only solves part of your issue, though. You are getting a TS compiler because the array is of type `string | SetStateAction<string>`, due to the fact that it has a mix of strings and functions. If you instead return an object from your hook, this will fix that. You can try the code below out here: https://playcode.io/1730806

```
export function useOpened() {
  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = React.useState("closed");
  const open = (depName: React.SetStateAction<string>) => setIsOpened(depName);
  return {isOpened, open}; // returning object instead of array
}

export function Component() {
  // decompose the object 
  const {isOpened: textOpened, open: openText} = useOpened();
  const {isOpened: chapterOpened, open: openChapter} = useOpened();

  ...
}
```

#### 3. You need some way to change the state back to 'closed'

As coded, you only ever set the value to the name of the shown componet. You can add simple check to the hook to see if the isOpen prop is already set to the name of the component, and if so, set it to close instead:

```
const open = (depName: React.SetStateAction<string>) => 
   setIsOpened(depName === isOpened ? "closed" : depName);
```

#### Putting it all to gether

The code below shows how you could pull this al together: https://playcode.io/1731497

```
export function useOpened() {
  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = React.useState("closed");
  const open = (depName: React.SetStateAction<string>) => 
    setIsOpened(depName === isOpened ? "closed" : depName);
  return {isOpened, open};
}

export function Component() {
  const {isOpened: textOpened, open: openText} = useOpened();
  const {isOpened: chapterOpened, open: openChapter} = useOpened();

  const item = {
    text: "Text",
    chapter: "Chapter Text",
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => openText(item.text)}>{item.text}</button>
        {textOpened === item.text && (
        <div>Text stuff</div>
      )}
      <button onClick={() => openChapter(item.chapter)}>{item.chapter}</button>
        {chapterOpened === item.chapter && (
        <div>Chapter description</div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

#### After thought

In the example below, swapped out the text prop for a boolean to toggle the `open` state. I also broke this up into two components. These two tweaks may end up being a little more clean and re-usable in the long run (generally breaking things up into smaller components helps in that regard), depending on your application: https://playcode.io/1731079

```
export function useOpened() {
  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = React.useState(false); // now boolean
  const toggle = () => setIsOpened(!isOpened); // now toggles
  return { isOpened, toggle };
}

// broken-out component
export function Openable({buttonText, textToDisplay}) {
  const { isOpened, toggle } = useOpened();

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => toggle()}>{buttonText}</button>
      {isOpened && (
        <div>{textToDisplay}</div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

// simplified original component
export function Component() {
  const item = {
    text: "Text",
    chapter: "Chapter Text",
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Openable buttonText={item.text} textToDisplay="Text stuff" />
      <Openable buttonText={item.chapter} textToDisplay="Chapter description" />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you, very clear explain. And how I make toggle, open/close. Like so: `const open = (depName: SetStateAction<string>, status: any) =>
    setIsOpened(status ? depName : "closed");` but does not work?

Comment: In my last example, I used a boolean instead of string to facilitate the closing. const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = React.useState(false);
  const open = (depName: React.SetStateAction<boolean>) => setIsOpened(depName);

Comment: Then in the button I toggle the state. <button onClick={() => open(!isOpened)}>{buttonText}</button>

Comment: I updated my answer to make that part a little more clear. This  live demo shows that working: https://playcode.io/1731079

Comment: If that helps solve the problem, don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: thanks. I prefer just one component (not two) and also aimed to keep the text prop instead of boolean. So I tried it with "status" as mentioned in my code above. Your toggle solution does not work for my purposes.

Comment: Gotcha. I updated my answer to show how to keep it as a string and one component. I made the change to two components and after thought. I would still keep that in mind, though, since will likely result in less code and more reusability in the long run for most applications. Your case may be different, though, but it's worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to toggle an item you need to move between 2 states. It might be `false` and `true` or key exists / absent.

Toggling multiple items requires multiples states, 1 for each item, so that one item's toggle state won't affect the rest.

To support a dynamic number of items, without using `useState` for each, your state can be an object, and you can change the state by adding/removing a key, where each key controls one item.

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const useMultiToggle = (initialOpen = []) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(
    () => Object.fromEntries(initialOpen.map(key => [key, true]))
  );
  
  const toggleIsOpen = useCallback(key => {
    // destructure the item out to check if it exists
    setIsOpen(({ [key]: open, ...rest }) => open // true or undefined
      ? rest // if exists remove from state
      : { ...rest, [key]: true } // add to state
    );
  }, []);
  
  return [isOpen, toggleIsOpen];
};

const items = ['Toggle 1', 'Toggle 2', 'Toggle 3', 'Toggle 4'];

const Demo = () => {
  const [isOpen, toggleIsOpen] = useMultiToggle(["Toggle 2", "Toggle 3"]);

  return (
    <div>
    {items.map(t => (
      <div key={t}>
        <button onClick={() => toggleIsOpen(t)}>{t}</button>
        {isOpen[t] && `${t} is open`}
      </div>
    ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Regarding Typescript. The custom hook returns a tuple of 2 - the object, and a toggle function. Because tuple in TS is just an array, you need to type it explicitly by stating the return type of the hook ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/multi-toggle-wzl6xh?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A28%2C15&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrld09s10006356jo9sjtxhr%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrld09s10002356j65c41ny6%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrld09s10003356jwgv1fwnl%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrld09s10005356j96ndwpgf%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrld09s10002356j65c41ny6%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrld09s00001356jga2kurwu%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpublic%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrmga7ad0002356j7f0rg1vr%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A5%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A25%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A5%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A25%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Ftsconfig.json%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrmgbgqs0002356jwn49s1na%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A28%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A15%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A28%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A15%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrld09s10002356j65c41ny6%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrmgbgqs0002356jwn49s1na%2522%257D%252C%2522clrld09s10005356j96ndwpgf%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrld09s10004356jrhv20ym6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrld09s10005356j96ndwpgf%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrld09s10004356jrhv20ym6%2522%257D%252C%2522clrld09s10003356jwgv1fwnl%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrld09s10003356jwgv1fwnl%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)):

```
type UseMultiToggleReturn = [Record<string, boolean>, (key: string) => void];

const useMultiToggle = (initialOpen: string[] = []): UseMultiToggleReturn => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(() =>
    Object.fromEntries(initialOpen.map((key) => [key, true]))
  );

  const toggleIsOpen = useCallback((key: string) => {
    setIsOpen(({ [key]: open, ...rest }) =>
      open ? rest : { ...rest, [key]: true }
    );
  }, []);

  return [isOpen, toggleIsOpen];
};
```